# Why can't I use outer property in inner class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The class `VoiceViewHolder` is a inner class of `VoiceAdapters`.

The `private val aHomeViewModel` is a property of the outer class `VoiceAdapters`.

I think `aHomeViewModel.delete(binding.amVoice)` in inner class `VoiceViewHolder` will be run correctly, but in fact it failed, why?

**Code**

```
class VoiceAdapters (private val aHomeViewModel: HomeViewModel):
        ListAdapter<MVoice, VoiceAdapters.VoiceViewHolder>(MVoiceDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VoiceViewHolder {
        return VoiceViewHolder(
            LayoutVoiceItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VoiceViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val aMVoice = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(aHomeViewModel, aMVoice)
    }

    class VoiceViewHolder (private val binding: LayoutVoiceItemBinding):
          RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        init {
            setControl()
        }                

        fun bind(bHomeViewModel: HomeViewModel, aMVoice: MVoice){
            binding.amVoice=aMVoice
            binding.aHomeViewModel=bHomeViewModel
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        fun setControl(){
            binding.btnDelete.setOnClickListener {
                aHomeViewModel.delete(binding.amVoice) //it's error
            }
        }
    }
}


class MVoiceDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MVoice>() {
   ...
}
```

Comment: A nested class marked as inner can access the members of its outer class.[Inner classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#inner-classes)

Comment: To clarify the other answers: your `VoiceViewHolder` class is just a nested class, not an inner class, so it has no implicit reference to the enclosing class and can't access its members.  To make it an inner class, define it with `inner class […]`.

Answer (score -1):

Hope to help you

```kotlin
inner class VoiceViewHolder { ... }
```